# When connecting via SSH, does the Diffie-Hellman key exchange take place over an unencrypted TCP session or does encryption occur before the exchange?

Tags: networking, ssh, encryption, tcp, wireshark

I'm a cybersecurity student and I'm eager to understand the basic processes of an SSH session. I wrote down the stages to the best of my ability, but need help understanding what happens right after the TCP handshake and right before the Diffie-Hellman key exchange. Please help!

Session Start/TCP Handshake

1. Client begins a session with Server by initiating a TCP handshake.

   > Assymetric Encryption for TCP Session
2. Server and Client negotiate back-and-forth and agree upon a mutually supported encryption protocol for the TCP session.

   > At this point, post-protocol-negotiation, it is unclear to me how their session is initially being encrypted. I used Wireshark to try and capture the Client or Server sending over their public key or something but could only see the protocol version exchange. Regardless, please explain this stage if you can.

   Client and Server negotiate a shared secret key for this session using the Diffie-Hellman algorithm in order to establish a symmetric-key encrypted session.
3. Client and Server begin process of producing temporary key pairs, using

   1. Shared prime number
   2. Encryption generator (typically AES)
   3. Private prime number (as private key).
4. Client and Server use these three to each generate their own public key that can be derived from their own private key.
5. Client and Server each share their generated public key with each other.
6. Client and Server each use their own private key, the other's public key and their original shared prime number to generate the same secret key.
7. Client and Server use this key as their shared secret key to encrypt and decrypt all future communication on this session.

   > At this stage, Client and Server have successfully established a symmetric-key-encrypted session without having needed to send the secret key over the network.

**If I got anything else wrong, I'd really appreciate any clarification.**

Comment: The [information security stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to ask about this. But the short answer is that it depends on which version of TLS, key agreement method, etc  is being used, but generally Diffie-Hellman or something similar *creates the encryption keys*, so by definition encryption doesn't start until after the exchange. Or to put it another way, the DH public keys *are public*.

Comment: @zx485 but it's crossposted, twice, with multiple answers.

Comment: @Gordon, SSH does not use TLS.

Comment: @user1686 D'oh! Brain fart, I read it as SSL...

Answer (score 1):

> At this point, post-protocol-negotiation, it is unclear to me how their session is initially being encrypted. I used Wireshark to try and capture the Client or Server sending over their public key or something but could only see the protocol version exchange. Regardless, please explain this stage if you can.

At this point it's not encrypted at all. You just can't see it in "Follow stream" view, because SSHv2 is a binary protocol, not a text-based protocol – after the initial version report, everything else is sent as binary packets with just *some* chunks of ASCII scattered here and there.

However, the different packet types are clearly visible in Wireshark's *dissected* view:

[image: Screenshot of Wireshark packet list]

Note that there is no packet that explicitly selects the desired algorithm; rather, each side provides a list ordered by preference, and the *first* algorithm that both sides agree on is always used. (The algorithm is explained in [SSH-TRANS section 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-7.1).) In this example, both sides have agreed to use ECDH.

[image: Screenshot of Wireshark dissected packet]

The same applies for encryption and MAC algorithms – the lists must be ordered by preference and the "most preferred" algorithm must be chosen, so it does not need to be explicitly confirmed.

> Client and Server begin process of producing temporary key pairs, using
>
> 1. Shared prime number
> 2. Encryption generator (typically AES)
> 3. Private prime number (as private key).

Yes, except... I'm not sure what you mean by "encryption generator" here.

Although DH uses the term 'generator', it doesn't refer to an algorithm – it's a *number*. I don't know maths well enough, but I believe it's [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group).